# Замена коллбека

Tags: callback, android, java

Здравствуйте, уважаемые!

У меня такой вопрос. Пишу велосипед в виде плеера аудио под андроид и столкнулся с проблемой. Для отображения прошедшего времени при проигрывании файла я использую класс **Handler** и метод **postDelayed**. И вроде бы все работает хорошо. Но проблема появляется такая. У меня есть список воспроизведения, и при клике на какую-либо песню она должна воспроизвестись. Допустим, я кликнул на песне и пошло воспроизведение. В специальном TextView отображается, сколько прошло времени. Потом я кликаю на другой песне, и старая песня должна перестать воспроизводиться, а вместо нее должна воспроизводиться новая. Все это мной реализовано, но проблема в отображении прошедшего времени. Когда я заменяю в плеере старую песню на новую и начинаю ее воспроизводить, я также заменяю коллбэк в Handler'е и в новом коллбэке уже слежу за прогрессом воспроизведения новой песни. Но почему-то старый коллбек не удаляется, и получается, что одновременно оба коллбека работают, из-за чего текствью, в котором отображается время, постоянно мерцает.

Вот мой код для коллбеков:

```
// сначала я удаляю старый коллбек
durationHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); 
player.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletion); 
// затем сбрасываю данные в плеере  
player.reset();
// устанавливаю для воспроизведения новую песню
player.setDataSource(filename); 
player.prepare();
final int duration = player.getDuration();
player.start();
// устанавливаю новый колбек
durationHandler.postDelayed(
    new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {     
        int progress = player.getCurrentPosition();
        demonstrator.setProgress(progress, duration);           
        durationHandler.postDelayed(this, REPEAT_TIME);         
                    }       
}, 400);

....

private OnCompletionListener onCompletion =  new OnCompletionListener() {       
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {          
    durationHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
}
};
```

Почему-то после начала проигрывания новой песни старый коллбек не удаляется, и с этого момента отрабатывают уже два коллбека. Как этого избежать и почему это происходит? Спасибо. заранее!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

removeCallbacksAndMessages, как и removeCallbacks, удаляет задачи, которые находятся в очереди, но не останавливает уже запущенный Runnable.
Нужно в самом Runnable реализовывать отмену, например, так:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
   private volatile boolean canceled = false;

   private void run()
   {
      if(canceled)
         return;

      int progress = player.getCurrentPosition();
      demonstrator.setProgress(progress, duration);           
      durationHandler.postDelayed(this, REPEAT_TIME);  
   }

   private void cancel()
   {
      canceled = true;
   }
}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {  
    runnable.cancel(); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужно создать отдельный экземпляр `Runnable`, чтобы иметь возможность останавливать его. Например, вот так:

```
Runnable durationRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run {
        //вот тут ваш код
    }
}
```

И потом замените

```
durationHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

На

```
durationHandler.removeCallbacks(durationRunnable);
```

Comment: спасибо большое! Ваш ответ тоже правильный, но, к сожалению, отметить как верный можно только один ответ!